# Scala macros: contextual DSL (limiting usage of macros to scopes)

Tags: scala, macros, dsl, scala-macros

I am attempting to build a DSL using Scala macros.

Suppose I have two macros

```
def add(x: Int, y: Int): Unit = macro Macros.mImpl
def builder(body: => Unit): Unit = macro Macros.builderImpl
```

where `Macros` is some object in which the macro behaviour is defined.

The intended use of these macros is to write things such as:

```
def example: Unit =
  builder {
    println("Hello, world!")
    // Some statements...
    add(4, 5)
    // Some more statements...
  }
```

The key thing here is that within the DSL, `add` should only be only allowed to occur within a `builder` block.

For example, the following should *not* be allowed:

```
def bad: Unit = add(4, 5)
```

I would like to find some way of ensuring that such occurrences of `add` are forbidden by the compiler.

Any solution will do: either through the type system (but I really don't see how), or through the macro mechanism itself.

Since macros are expanded from the innermost context outwards (that is, bottom up, not top down), I don't see how I can achieve this from within the macro definition of `add`.

(Feel free to modify the return types or definition sites of the macros if it helps; they were chosen for the sake of a simple example.)

Comment: This is a little tricky since nested macros get expanded from the inside out (even for by-name parameters), but it's possible if you examine the enclosing context from inside `mImpl`.

Comment: @TravisBrown Do you know how I can examine the context from inside `mImpl`? I understand that all of the `enclosingX` methods on `blackbox.Context` are deprecated, except `enclosingMacros` and `enclosingPos`. I thought `enclosingMacros` was going to give me what I needed (i.e., that it would return a list of contexts that would include the `builder` macro, but it did not). Perhaps I misunderstood what `enclosingMacros` was for, but the docs weren't super clear. The method `openMacros` wasn't much use either for the same reason. Do you have any specific ideas on how to examine the context?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible without one of the other `enclosingX` methods.

Comment: It seems my question is related to the discussions [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-debate/f4CLmYShX6Q) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-debate/f4CLmYShX6Q), and I fear that you are right...

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `enclosingXXX` methods, because they have been deprecated in scala.reflect and might be unsupported in scala.meta.

Comment: Can you turn `add` into a `@compileTimeOnly` method that's expanded by the enclosing `builder` macro?

Comment: If you mean that the `builder` macro would be responsible for implementing the current effect of the `add` macro, by traversing the subtree until it finds an `add` DefDef, then yes, I guess I could. However, traversing the subtree always sounds like a lot of effort, although when I've done it before it was in the days before quasiquotes, etc. Is there any easier way to do this, rather than matching on the DefDef etc. case classes all the way down the tree?

Comment: @EugeneBurmako Is there any easy way to traverse the subtree in order to find the `add` method call? Or do I have to pattern match on everything until I find it?

Comment: You could subclass `Transformer` and then pattern match for an `Apply`, whose `.symbol` is the same as symbol of the `add` method.